# Non-Capture Cucumber Expression

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Transitioning off of Regex and to cucumber expressions.  Had a question about how to do non-capturing groups?

```
"I see the unread badge display {string} unread message(s) for the chat with the {string} user/personal-group/official-group"
```

Previously it was:

```
"^I see the unread badge display REGEX unread message(?: |s) for the chat with the REGEX (?:user/personal group/official group)$"
```

I was told the - will link characters but it is not reading that in my feature files.  What's the best way to handle non-capturing words?